# What's the difference between REF and HAL?

Tags: directx, directx-9

The question wasn't formulated exactly right because it's a bit difficult to do in 1 sentence, so the real question is:
The function which creates the object representing a device in Direct3D9 looks like this.

```
  HRESULT IDirect3D9::CreateDevice(
    UINT Adapter,
    D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType,
    HWND hFocusWindow,
    DWORD BehaviorFlags,
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *pPresentationParameters,
    IDirect3DDevice9** ppReturnedDeviceInterface
    );
```

`Adapter` UINT argument refers to a particular video card used on target computer but `DeviceType` argument refers to either *HAL* or *REF*. So what's the point of specifying some particular video card (e.g. 0) and *REF* device type ? Isn't *REF* some abstract instance which is emulated by processor and doesn't have any relation to video card?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're right. Reference devices implement most DirectX functionality in software and do not rely on the graphics driver. In turn, they are quite slow and should be used only for testing. There are two reasons why you would want a reference device:

If your graphics card does not support the DirectX features you want to use, you can use a reference device because it will support every feature. However, this makes only sense during development (if you're temporarily on a low-end machine).

If you get strange results, it could be a driver issue. To rule that out, you can check with a reference device. If this gives you the same results, the problem is somewhere in your code. If it gives you correct results, the graphics driver is buggy.

Comment: Note that on modern Windows platforms, using [WARP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082.aspx) rather than REF is much faster for debugging driver issues.